# Java socket server can not read string correctly from a objective-c client, why?

Tags: java, objective-c, sockets

I have written a java socket server, and an objective-c socket client, when the client connect to the server it will send string "server\n". server side can not read it correctly, it's readed as follow:
��Y�~�Ü@{Eu`�n��N    �8���������,��,�+�$�#�
both sides use utf-8, how to make them work?

Object socket client:

```
NSString *jsonStr = @"server\n";
    const char * clientTextData = [jsonStr 
cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"=========>%@==========>%s",jsonStr,clientTextData);
    NSData* lengthData=[NSData dataWithBytes:clientTextData length:200];
    [gcdSocket writeData:lengthData withTimeout:-1 tag:110];
```

Java server side:

```
public void run()
{
    try {
        InputStream is = sk.getInputStream(); //sk is socket object
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String typeString = br.readLine();
```

Comment: Java uses utf-16 by default.  How sure are you that the Java side expects utf-8?

Comment: Create your object like this - `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));` .. Let me know if that helps or not, if it doesn't help then let me know how was the output, depending on that you need to figure a mechanism to explicitly use "UTF8" in your objective c code as well.